# Inquiry: Why am I getting a clang error on my OSX terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, terminal, clang

I have the following files on a linux VM:

```
gc.h
gc.c
test.c
test.out
```

I run the command in terminal:

```
gcc -g test.c gc.c gc.h -o test.out
```

Everything compiles. I then run the same files (I copied them over) and run the command on my OSX terminal:

```
gcc -g test.c gc.c gc.h -o test.out
```

I then get the following error:

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

Is there a simple reason why I am getting this error? I don't understand as I am not generating multiple files? I also googled this, but couldn't find anything relevant.

I have appreciated your clues. I get now that it has to do with the fact that I am running OSX 10.9 Mavericks and xcode 5.0.2. So now I am in the process of trying to switch over to gcc48. So I thought doing it would be easiest with `brew install gcc48`. I just did a major update with brew last week and I saw this message:

```
Error: No available formula for gcc48
Searching taps...
homebrew/versions/gcc48
```

Anyone see this before? I am somewhat not very experienced with the brew tool. What does this mean? Yes, I googled this, but just don't seem to have a lot of luck today. Then, I found this [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) and I think I got it working. But not quite sure why the normal command wouldn't work as intended?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you compiling that poor header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to compile a header file:

```
gcc -g test.c gc.c gc.h -o test.out
                   ^^^^
```

clang is interpreting this as an attempt to precompile the header. While a useful thing to do in general, this isn't compatible with *also* compiling your application in the same breath.

Remove that from the compiler command line and you'll be fine.

Comment: This. Under normal circumstances, don't compile header files. The compiler will understand what you intend to do as long as the file is in the header search path.

Comment: I am considering this the answer as it allows me to send it to another individual without them changing their environment. However, I think in the future I will use gcc48 when having to stay in pure linux environments, but have to develop on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

OSX uses clang not gcc in their gcc command. Just do a gcc --version on both your linux vm and your osx machine and you'll notice that they are different compilers.

You could install the real gcc using brew (e.g., `brew install gcc48`) and then use that on your osx if you want to get the exact same behavior as on your linux vm.

Comment: I tried installing gcc48. I get the following error:               Error: No available formula for gcc48
Searching taps...
homebrew/versions/gcc48  sigh...just one of those days.

Comment: While this may be true, this isn't why the OP is having his issue. See the above answer for the correct answer.

Comment: @GeekyOmega yes, you will need to tap that. I think brew tap homebrew/versions && brew install gcc48 should work.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed was the issue with gcc48. Learning things step by step. I gave you some rep for your comments.